# How can I create a parent and several children with a button?

Tags: apex, custom-button

Here is the code as it stands right now :

```
public class MyControllerOppAndCBC {

public void CreateOpportunityWithChildren(Id  accountId) {

    // Query the countries related to this account
    List<Country__c> countryProfiles = [SELECT Id
                                            , Name
                                        FROM Country__c 
                                        WHERE Account_Name__c = :accountId];
    // Lists for DML operations
    List<Opportunity> OpportunitiesToInsert         = new List<Opportunity>();                                  
    List<OpportunityChild__c> OppyChildrenToInsert  = new List<OpportunityChild__c>();                              

    // create an opportunity to dangle opportunity children from
    Opportunity oppy = new Opportunity(Name = 'Your Oppy Name'
                                        , AccountId = accountId 
                                        , StageName = 'Prospecting'
                                        , CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(7));

    // add it to the list for later DML
    OpportunitiesToInsert.add(oppy);

    // for each countryProfile queried earlier, create an OpportunityChild
    for (Country__c countryProfile: countryProfiles) {

        // set the fields on the OpportunityChild
        OpportunityChild__c oppyChild   = new OpportunityChild__c();
        //oppyChild.Stage__c              = 'Prospecting';
        oppyChild.Account_Name__c        = accountId;
        oppyChild.Client_Country_Profile__c            = countryProfile.Id;

        // presumably there's a name like 'Argentina' in the name field
        oppyChild.Name                  = 'CBC ' + countryProfile.Name;

        // set a reference between this child object and it's parent
        // (presuming there is a relationship between the two named Opportunity)
        oppyChild.Opportunity__r = oppy;

        // add this child to the list for later DML
        OppyChildrenToInsert.add(oppyChild);
    }

    // set up a transaction so that we can roll back in the event anything fails
    System.Savepoint sp1 = Database.setSavepoint();

    // try / catch around all of this DML
    try {
        // if any exist, first insert the parents
        if (!OpportunitiesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            insert OpportunitiesToInsert;
        }

        // if any exist, insert the children
        // ( Note: probably wouldn't do this work if there weren't any parents )
        if (!OppyChildrenToInsert.isEmpty()) {

            // for all of the children that we are inserting, reach through the
            // relationship between the two objects and get the ID assigned
            // on the parent earlier during that DML operation
            for (OpportunityChild__c oppyChild : OppyChildrenToInsert) {

                // is there a relationship to a parent?
                if (oppyChild.Opportunity__r != null) {

                    // reach through the relationship and get the ID from the parent
                    // and set that id value on the child
                    oppyChild.Opportunity__c = oppyChild.Opportunity__r.Id; 
                }
            }

            // now that all of the children have the ID values of their parents
            insert OppyChildrenToInsert;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log the exception
        system.debug(ex);

        // something failed, roll back the entire transaction
        Database.rollback(sp1);
    }
}
}
```

When I was unsure how to handle the "unexpected token error : void" error, I thought I might be required to name a class before the method so I put this in :

public class MyControllerOppAndChild {

But now I'm getting a "File name mismatch with class name : MyControllerOppAndChild" error. My intention is to call this code with a custom button. I've never done that before, but I thought I might need to use the code as a class anyway. Am I wrong here ?

One other thing : I am unable to write to the oppyChild.Name field because it is an Automatic Number field. How should I handle that ? I don't think I'm able to create an Auto Number through a button, am I ?

Thank you very much for your help and effort.

Comment: You cannot call a class from a button you can call a Visual force page from a button,enter the chat room and one of us can walk through with you what you need to do !!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original code has a mix of both single a account and trigger context so for this example I wrote it with the single account context. If you can provide more information about where the button is defined, how it is going to be configured and how this code will be called, it could be further refined but this may be enough to get you going.

The behavior is in essence:

- Get Countries with the provided accountId
- Create one Opportunity
- For each country, create OpportunityChild & relate to parent
- Insert Opportunity
- Modify OpportunityChildren with related parent's new Id
- Insert OpportunityChildren

This pattern of inserting parents and then retrieving the id through a reference before insert of a child is a handy one.

---

```
public void CreateOpportunityWithChildren(Id accountId) {

    // Query the countries related to this account
    List<Country__c> countryProfiles = [SELECT Id
                                            , Name
                                        FROM Country__c 
                                        WHERE Account__c = :accountId];
    // Lists for DML operations
    List<Opportunity> OpportunitiesToInsert         = new List<Opportunity>();                                  
    List<OpportunityChild__c> OppyChildrenToInsert  = new List<OpportunityChild__c>();                              

    // create an opportunity to dangle opportunity children from
    Opportunity oppy = new Opportunity(Name = 'Your Oppy Name'
                                        , AccountId = accountId
                                        , StageName = 'Prospecting'
                                        , CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(7));

    // add it to the list for later DML
    OpportunitiesToInsert.add(oppy);

    // for each countryProfile queried earlier, create an OpportunityChild
    for (Country__c countryProfile: countryProfiles) {

        // set the fields on the OpportunityChild
        OpportunityChild__c oppyChild   = new OpportunityChild__c();
        oppyChild.Stage__c              = 'Prospecting';
        oppyChild.AccountName__c        = accountId;
        oppyChild.Country__c            = countryProfile.Id;

        // presumably there's a name like 'Argentina' in the name field
        oppyChild.Name                  = 'OpportunityChild ' + countryProfile.Name;

        // set a reference between this child object and it's parent
        // (presuming there is a relationship between the two named Opportunity)
        oppyChild.Opportunity__r = oppy;

        // add this child to the list for later DML
        OppyChildrenToInsert.add(oppyChild);
    }

    // set up a transaction so that we can roll back in the event anything fails
    System.Savepoint sp1 = Database.setSavepoint();

    // try / catch around all of this DML
    try {
        // if any exist, first insert the parents
        if (!OpportunitiesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            insert OpportunitiesToInsert;
        }

        // if any exist, insert the children
        // ( Note: probably wouldn't do this work if there weren't any parents )
        if (!OppyChildrenToInsert.isEmpty()) {

            // for all of the children that we are inserting, reach through the
            // relationship between the two objects and get the ID assigned
            // on the parent earlier during that DML operation
            for (OpportunityChild__c oppyChild : OppyChildrenToInsert) {

                // is there a relationship to a parent?
                if (oppyChild.Opportunity__r != null) {

                    // reach through the relationship and get the ID from the parent
                    // and set that id value on the child
                    oppyChild.Opportunity__c = oppyChild.Opportunity__r.Id; 
                }
            }

            // now that all of the children have the ID values of their parents
            insert OppyChildrenToInsert;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log the exception
        system.debug(ex);

        // something failed, roll back the entire transaction
        Database.rollback(sp1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can post the class that you are receiving this error in (by editing your original question and adding an update to it) I can probably answer it more accurately. Unexpected token 'void', means exactly that... the word 'void' shouldn't be where you have it for it to be valid code. Without seeing your code in it's entirety I can only speculate where the problem lie.

Comment: Mark - I have updated my original post to show the current code and give a better explanation of what is going on with it and a couple questions. Thank you very much for your help in this. You've been really great.

Answer (score 1):

try this out :

```
ah my bad i am creating a oppty for the account and then creating child records for the newly created opptys. I have the new code now that creates a new opp and a child oppty and relates to the account's country records
//Assumptions 

1) Account has countries as children
2) You need a button that creates oppty and child for oppties and relate it to the account's child countries on button click 
3) you are working on individual accounts from where the button will be clicked.
public MyController(){
    //Grab the account Id to which the oppty should relate
        current_Page_Id = ApexPages.currentpage().getParamters().get('id');
        //Get the plural name for the child ( countries) if the name of the object is countries related to account and plural name is countries related to accounts 
        // use countries_related_to_accounts__r since we are using relationship queries here.
        acc          = [select id,(select id from countries_related_to_accounts__r) from Account where Id=: current_Page_Id];
        children     = new List<child_for_new_oppty__c>();
    }

    public pagereference saveMychildren(){
        // start populating the data for saving an oppty, put in all the required fields with values 
        if(acc != null){
        //for all the countries related to the current account you are working on,create a new oppty and once the 
        for(countries_related_to_account__c cont : acc. countries_related_to_account__r){
            opportunity opp                     = new opportunity();
            oppty.name              = 'My first oppty';
            oppty.countries__c      = cont.Id;
            oppty.add(opp);
        }
            database.saveresult[] SR = database.Insert(oppty,false);

            //Make sure the oppty is inserted.

            for(database.saveresult S: SR){
                if(S.Issuccess()){
                    for(opportunity o: oppty){
                        child_for_new_oppty__c  c = new child_for_new_oppty__c ();
                        c.OpportunityId = o.Id;
                        c.name          = 'My new child';
                        children.add(c);
                    }   
                }
            }
            database.saveresult[] S_child = database.insert(children);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: rao - thank you very much for your input. I really appreciate it. However, I'm a little confused by your code. It seems like it's creating an Opp and then Country records as children to that Opp, instead of creating an Opp and then OppChildren__c records for each already existing Country__c record for the Account. Am I reading this wrong ? I probably am. I'm sorry if that's a stupid question.

Comment: that code is awesome. One thing : Your #3 assumption is not true. The button will actually be clicked in a separate object named Overview__c. So, I'll need to get the Account id in a different way. There is an Account_name__c lookup field in the Overview__c object. If I change the 3rd line (current_Page_Id....) to this : current_Account_ID = ApexPages.currentpage().get('Account_Name'); and then use the current_Account_ID in the query instead of the current_Page_Id should it all work properly ? It seems like it would but I could be wrong. Thank you very much for you time and help.

Comment: I just realized that your new code is creating a new Opp for each Country, but it's really only supposed to be creating one new Opp - and then an OppChild for each Country.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can point you down the right path. First, you want to be passing certain values into your controller. One of them is the AccountId which should be part of the URL that follows the ? mark in the browser. The Account Id is the parent of the Opportunity. So, `MyExtID__c='SAP111111' is actually MyExtID = AccountId.` Its not something you can hardcode into your controller. Instead it's a variable that's passed into it.

The same applies here:

```
 Opportunity parentOpportunity = new Opportunity(
        Name='Hallie', // <- This will also be passed in
        Name= OppName;
       // MyExtID__c='SAP111111');
MyExtId__c =  AccountId;
```

You'll need to look in your org to see what fields are required to create a new opportunity. Those fields need to be passed into your controller. Typically, you'll need to include at lease the Owner.Id, Account.Id, Opportunity Name, Stage, Close and perhaps several other things depending on what your organization requires. You'll have to go into set-up to see what's required. Once you know, you'll do something like this:

```
Opportunity nwOpp = new Opportunity [Name = OppName, Account = AcctId, Owner = OwnrId, StageName = 'prospecting' (or some variable you've passed with another value), CloseDate = Date.Today().addDays(7), Probability = prob];

Database.Insert(nwOpp);
```

You'll need to do the same for each of the child opportunities except that if I'm not mistaken, each of those would have a different RecordType where they'd be shown as children of the Parent Opportunity e.g. the Parent Id or OppName. I believe you'd do this by setting the "RelatedTo" equal to the Id of the Parent Opportunity.

So, you're headed in the right direction, but need to establish the setters and getters with all the required information you'll need in order to perform your queries, initialize your variables, then insert the results into the database as it sounds as though you don't especially want to return the results although I think it would be a good idea to indicate to the user that the opportunities have been inserted into the database by returning something to them.